# Element not found using path

Tags: java, ios, appium

I'm trying to automate an iOS app using XPath
I'm using Appium element locator and my script needs to click on a button. 
The xpath giving by Appium is not found and I don't understand why.

Here's the screenshot of the Appium locator:

[image: Appium locator]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLz06.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNn00.png)
My code:

```
driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='RENOUVELER CE TRAJET']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, do not use XPath where you can obtain another locator. In your particular example you better use `accessabilityId` instead of `Xpath`. So use this code:

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("RENOUVELER CE TRAJET").click();
```

Comment: Thanks but I've tried to use the accessabilityId and it's not working

Comment: then use `driver.findElementByName("RENOUVELER CE TRAJET").click();`

Comment: Same result :/ I know maybe it's a stupid remark but if the return to the line in the button make the difference? (check the screenshot)

Comment: yes it was that, i've add \n after RENOUVELER and It worked
driver.findElementByName("RENOUVELER\n CE TRAJET").click();

Comment: what do you mean by "return to the line in the button make the difference"? if you want an element and click on it on that screen (that you provided above in my comment) you either may use `accessabilityId` or `findElementByName`. If both of it is not working, you are doing smething wrong. I guess you are on different screen.

Comment: @HaithemKefi you can check it and try to find it by accessabilityId and it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Could you ask the dev to remove the spacing in the id? See if it works if the accessibilityid change

Answer (score 0):

Visually deceptive, but usually appium works on what you see is what you get.

The screenshot provided by OP has the button with the text-flow continued on the next line.

So in order to get the accessibility id right.

Always use `\n` on where the string got divided into new line.

```java
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("RENOUVELER\nCE TRAJET");
```